# What happens to opened files when my program crash?

Tags: python, operating-system

When my program crashes with opened files what happens to them, are they automatically closed?

I'm aware the correct way is to use `with` but I'm curious what will happen when I don't.

```py
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')

# Example code that crashes the problem
a = 5 / 0
```

compared to

```py
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = 5 / 0
```

If the opened files are automatically closed when the program crashes what is the benefit of using the `with` syntax?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In these two cases, it is just your program which ‘crashes’ and not Python itself.

Comment: Are you *planning* on your program crashing?

Comment: @ScottHunter I want to open many many files and with the other syntax it would be nested too deep. So I want to switch to not using them. I would like to know about the behavior of opened files since during development and test, the program will crash a lot.

Comment: So what happens with the opened files? @quamrana

Comment: If they are opened for reading, not much happens when the program crashes.

Comment: Since your program has crashed, I think that python will still manage reference counted memory, which in the case of files might close them. Try it yourself with files opened for write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `with` closes the file automatically.  Not using `with` and not explicitly closing your file means that as long as your application is running it will leave the file open.

If your program crashes the file will be released and the lock will expire.  Regardless of with.  If your program hangs however, and you did not leave the `with` statement, or simply used open, then you will keep the file open as long as your application is hung.